# How to horizontally center content of iframe (Google Map)? Usual methods not working

Tags: html, css, iframe

I want to get an embedded map effect like this one: http://themeforest.net/item/yalu-creative-multipurpose-template-html/full_screen_preview/4569177 except I need to do it with an iframe not JS like in the example.
My sections have a max width but the map's container is set to overflow:visible to allow the iframe to show through.

I have tried the following CSS on the map div and the iframe itself too:

```
display:block;
margin:auto;
text-align: center;
```

and they didn't work.
Please help... thank you.

My HTML:

```
<div class="section">
<h2>Where we are </h2>
    <div class="map">
        <iframe width="605" height="250" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="https://maps.google.co.uk/maps?f=q&amp;source=s_q&amp;hl=en&amp;geocode=&amp;q=3-4+High+Street+Hitchin+SG5+1BH&amp;aq=&amp;sll=51.48931,-0.08819&amp;sspn=0.868785,2.113495&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;hq=&amp;hnear=3-4+High+St,+Hitchin+SG5+1BH,+United+Kingdom&amp;t=m&amp;ll=51.947915,-0.278864&amp;spn=0.013226,0.051842&amp;z=14&amp;iwloc=A&amp;output=embed"></iframe>
    </div>
</div>
```

My CSS:

```
div.section { 
 width: 80%; 
 max-width: 600px; 
 margin: 0 auto 40px;
}

div.map { 
 margin: auto; 
 width: 100%; 
 height: 25rem;
}
```

I also have the following script going on, to set the iframe width depending on screen width (the default 605 width is there because iframes must have a set width in the HTML AFAIK:

```
if($(window).width() < 1100) {
    $('iframe').attr("width", $(window).width());
}
else {
    $('iframe').attr("width", "1100");
}
```

Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/Ykx2w/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, now I am confused. I would suggest to be more specific and clearly indicate what you are trying to achieve. Following the link you posted, I do not see any map, hence you may be talking either about `id="main-slider"` (which fills all available space, but not centered horizontally) or `section id="main"` (centered horizontally, but has static width). Which one do you need?

Also I updated my last sample to work under IE browser and auto fill all available horizontal space (resize the window): http://jsfiddle.net/Ykx2w/3/. If that's not what you need - try to describe better your need.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't realise that the link did not show the map; I copied the URL from the page with the map but it appears that it's the same as for the other pages in that template preview! If you click on 'Contact' in the menu of the link I posted in the original question, you should see the map. Apologies for the confusion.
I've been trying and I don't think there is a solution to this really - even if we get it to fill the available space (which I'd managed to do originally) it won't center horizontally on the pin. Your fiddle is the closest solution as far as I can see, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I did small changes here: [centered iframe](http://jsfiddle.net/34BYV/5/). Basically you need this CSS rule only:

```
div.map iframe {
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

Comment: As I said, that doesn't work unfortunately. I have added the JQuery to your fiddle, and you can see it there: http://jsfiddle.net/Ykx2w/

Comment: Did you look at the example that I said I need it to look like? The map needs to be the full width of the page, using 'overflow: visible' or some other method that I may not have thought of.